# Embed Pandas df html table in email using python 3

Tags: python, html-table, embed, html-email

I am trying to embed and send html table created with `pandas` `.to_html`.

I'm happy to either send the df directly to the email or from a file.

So far I can embed images with the following:

```
fp = open(attachment, 'rb')                                                    
img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(attachment))
msg.attach(img)
```

I have experimenting with this which attached the df but not embeds for some reason.

```
fp = open(att1, 'r')                                                    
img = MIMEText(fp.read(),'html')
fp.close()
img.add_header('Content-ID', '<att1>')
msg.attach(img)
```

Alternatively i can send the df data to an email but sends as unformatted text and can't seems to work out this approach with formatting (i.e.) table with simple border.

```
df = dFrame(q2) 
tbl = '{df}'
tbl = df.to_html(index=False,justify='center')
msgText = MIMEText('<b>%s</b><br><html src="cid:%s"><br>' % (body, tbl), 'html')
msg.attach(msgText)
```

More complete code for embedded image which i desire to adjust for embed html tables.

```
def sndFile1():
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

    att1 = path + 'df.html'
    att2 = path + 'Indices.png'
    att3 = path + 'Segments.png'

    subject = 'Market Update'
    body = 'This Weeks Report'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["To"] = myEml
    msg["From"] = myEml
    msg["Subject"] = subject

    msgText = MIMEText('<b>%s</b><br><html src="cid:%s"><img src="cid:%s"><img src="cid:%s"><br>' % (body, att1, att2, att3), 'html')
    msg.attach(msgText)

    fp = open(att1, 'r')                                                    
    img = MIMEText(fp.read(),'html')
    fp.close()
    img.add_header('Content-ID', '<att1>')
    msg.attach(img)

    fp = open(att2, 'rb')                                                    
    img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(att2))
    msg.attach(img)

    fp = open(att3, 'rb')                                                    
    img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(att3))
    msg.attach(img)

    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(mySMTP, smtpPORT)
    s.login(myUID,myPASS)
    s.sendmail(myEml,myRec, msg.as_string())
```

**...and here's my final code with some minor tweaks to msgText based on solution from** **all working great! thanks**

```
def sndFile1():
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

    att1 = path + 'df.html'
    att2 = path + 'Indices.png'
    att3 = path + 'Segments.png'
    subject = 'Market Update'
    body = 'This Weeks Report'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["To"] = myEml
    msg["From"] = myEml
    msg["Subject"] = subject

    fp = open(att1, 'r')                                                   
    html = fp.read()
    fp.close()

    msgText = MIMEText('<b>%s</b><br><%s><br><img src="cid:%s"><br><img src="cid:%s"><br>' % (body, html, att2, att3), 'html')
    msg.attach(msgText)

    with open(att2, 'rb') as fp:
        img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(att2))
    msg.attach(img)

    with open(att3, 'rb') as fp:                                                   
        img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(att3))
    msg.attach(img)

    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(mySMTP, smtpPORT)
    s.login(myUID,myPASS)
    s.sendmail(myEml,myRec, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified snippet you provided. Main change was not using html dataframe as attachment but just insert it in message body.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

with open('df.html', 'w') as fil:
    df.head().to_html(fil)

att1 = 'df.html'
att2 = path + 'Indices.png'
att3 = path + 'Segments.png'
subject = 'Market Update'
body = 'This Weeks Report'

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg["To"] = myEml
msg["From"] = myEml
msg["Subject"] = subject

with open(att1, 'r') as fp:                                                    
    html = fp.read()

msgText = MIMEText('<b>%s</b><br>%s<img src="cid:%s"><br><img src="cid:%s"><br>' % (body, html, att2, att3), 'html')
msg.attach(msgText)

with open(att2, 'rb') as fp:
    img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(att2))
msg.attach(img)

with open(att3, 'rb') as fp:                                                   
    img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(att3))
msg.attach(img)

s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(mySMTP, smtpPORT)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.login(username,password)
s.sendmail(me,you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```